# Creating ear package using one pom with maven

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I want to create ear application with one ejb project and dependencies (without war file). Is it possible to specify build configuration in one pom.xml to avoid unnecessary multiplication of application modules (I have about 8 projects witch will be packaged this way and if I would do this "standard" way I would have to create 8*3=24 modules/poms). I don't want to put all my applications into one ear, because I need to could undeploy/redeploy them separately.

Right now I have two solutions:

- Create ear in standard way with module structure:

  > ```
  > project
  >   ejb
  >     src
  >     pom.xml
  >   ear
  >     pom.xml
  >   pom.xml
  > ```

  But as I mentioned it's creating multiplication of modules.
- Create jar with dependencies using maven-shade-plugin

  ```
  <build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals><goal>shade</goal></goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <finalName>project</finalName>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ```

  But with this solution I get jar instead of ear and my dependencies are mixed with my code.

Is there any other way to create deployable application with only ejb and dependencies with maven using single pom.xml?

Comment: What i don't understand is: `multiplication of modules`? You have for every purpose a single responsibile (module)? What is the problem?

Comment: As I mentioned I have 8 projects, each of them I want to be separate ear, so to acomplish this I would need 24 pom.xml (I meant pom=module), 16 of them will be only for packaging application as ear. If I have one pom for one application the structure will be more clear and adding another application would not be copy-pasting of this structure.

Comment: You are violating Separation of concerns principle. You say having a single module which contains EJB/EAR means you need to compile code run tests and furthermore you need to create an ear file which contains the ejb. If you like to go this way try it but i'm not sure if that will really work.